# Weird Extra Looping

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still a bit new to Python, but, I feel *really* stupid right now 'cause I've just spent an hour trying to figure out why this for loop isn't doing what I want. I shouldn't be spending an hour on a for loop. Anyway, I'm trying to generate a list of dictionaries, and give them each a unique number, so I do this...

```
def initiate(n):
    records = {'num':0,'blah':0,'doubleblah':0}
    x = []
    for i in range(n):
        x.append(records)
        x[i]['num'] = i
    return x

x = initiate(4)
print(x)
```

I expect the function to return this --

```
[
 {'num': 0, 'doubleblah': 0, 'blah': 0}, 
 {'num': 1, 'doubleblah': 0, 'blah': 0}, 
 {'num': 2, 'doubleblah': 0, 'blah': 0}, 
 {'num': 3, 'doubleblah': 0, 'blah': 0}
]
```

But it actually returns this --

```
[
 {'num': 3, 'doubleblah': 0, 'blah': 0}, 
 {'num': 3, 'doubleblah': 0, 'blah': 0}, 
 {'num': 3, 'doubleblah': 0, 'blah': 0}, 
 {'num': 3, 'doubleblah': 0, 'blah': 0}
]
```

...when I add a few print statements into the function, I discover that it seems to be adding the number to every dictionary in the list, instead of just the current dictionary. I really don't see how the code would add to all the dict's, since I explicitly use `x[i] = i` to add the number to the current dictionary only.

Comment: Would you get the same results if you moved the code to build x into a separate function? It might be an issue with the loop referencing the last value of x within its scope

Comment: +1 for an excellently structured question. Short self-contained code, expected output, and actual output - if only every question had these things!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's happening is that you're appending a reference to the same dictionary to the list each time.

```
print list(map(id, initiate(4)))
# [42283920, 42283920, 42283920, 42283920]
```

Your function is correctly written as:

```
def initiate(n):
    return [ {'num': i, 'blah': 0, 'doubleblah': 0} for i in range(n) ]
```

This produces a new instance of a dictionary each time.

Comment: Alternatively, OP could append `records.copy()` instead of appending `records` -- Your way is probably more idiomatic, but mentioning `copy` might make it a little more obvious what is actually going wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Going with users theme, here a solution.

But its worth noting that dict.copy is a shallow copy, meaning your original issue will persist if there are non-primitive members of that source records.
More precicely, the issue stems from the members being mutable data types.
Integers, strings, floats, booleans, and a couple other built-in types are immutable.
Immutability is a property that means the object cannot be changed once it is created.
Dicts and lists, for instance, are mutable

```
def initiate(n, records):
    x = []
    for i in range(n):
        x.append (records.copy())
        x[i]['num'] = i
    return x
    
records = {'num':0,'blah':0,'doubleblah':0}
x = initiate(4, records)

print(x)
```

```
[{'num': 0, 'blah': 0, 'doubleblah': 0}, {'num': 1, 'blah': 0, 'doubleblah': 0}, {'num': 2, 'blah': 0, 'doubleblah': 0}, {'num': 3, 'blah': 0, 'doubleblah': 0}]
[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def initiate(n):
    my_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        my_list.append(
            {
                'num': i,
                'blah': 0,
                'doubleblah': 0
            }
        )
    
    return my_list
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.